# C++ Algorithmic overload for operator- for a custom integer class

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector

I'm having a problem with an exercise in C++.
I'm supposed to make a class that can hold a number of any possible size, that is "Only limited by the hardware of the machine".
The idea is to store data that represents any number.

my concept is something like this:

```
class Unlimited
{
public:
    Unlimited();
    Unlimited(const string& value);
    /* bunchload of operator overloading
     * and helping functions */
private:
    vector<int> numbersVector;
    bool isPositive;
    /* another bunchload of helping functions */
}
```

Edit : I'm also limited to 4-5 lines in each function, so every function has to be logically separated to other functions.

So what I have to do is the make good use of an STL container and effectively use operators.
I've decided to use vector (over list).
Each cell in a vector contains an int from 0 to 9, each representing another digit in the Unlimited. The cells are ordered backwards from the actual meaning,

Meaning that when I call .toString() to an Unlimited that has a vector of {5, 3, 9, 2},

I would in return get `"2935"` as a return value.

Adding two Unlimiteds works like this:
You sum up all cells of one vector with another vector `{a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], ...}` and so on.
You then go over the new vector from 0 to size(), setting each cell with the following manner

```
vector[i+1] += vector[i] / 10;
vector[i] %= 10;
```

So this kinda works (except for the `vector[i+1]=X` thing because you need to allocate further space if the cell isn't already reallocated.

So this is the operator+ idea.

Now, when we talk about operator- that's a whole difference algorithm and I can't seem to get a hold of it.

Not so much because of negative numbers, I'm sure I can figure something with that if I have the base for the algorithm.

If anyone manages the figure something out, even just a clue, I'll be thankful.

Comment: If you know the result of subtraction is non-negative, the process is almost the same. Build a vector {a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1], ...}. Then `vector[i+1] += vector[i] / 10;` and `vector[i] = (vector[i] + 10) % 10` in a loop (`+ 10` is there because `-1 % 10 == -1` but we want it to be `9`). After that, kill leading zeroes in a loop.

Comment: For a negative result, just swap the arguments. To know whether the result is negative or non-negative, you will need a comparison function. But you are probably going to write it anyway.

Comment: 1. Are we talking about an unlimited integer type?
2. Would you consider using the full 32 bits worth of storage in your vector and then implement traditional operations with carry bits etc?
3. What operators does your exercise require? +, -, *, /, ++, --, ==, !=, <, ...

Comment: note that `vector<char>` is more than enough for what you are doing no need for `vector<int>`.

Comment: Okay. so it requires basics such as +/+=, -/-=, */*= for the most of it. also ^(power) and also << which isn't really a problem since I already implemented .toString()
For the comparisons, thanks for the note, it actually made me think for a moment and I can deffinitly implement the comparison method.
Gassa, thanks for the note, i'll try that out! thanks guys.

Drax, i'm aware, but it's part of the exercise, I've discussed it with my 'mentor' and it's more of a design choice rather than an efficiency choice. But thanks for the note anyway

Comment: I think you would have more fun then if you solved the problem by thinking of the vector an infinite storage of bits rather than the decimal representation that you currently have. It would be analog to the principle of additions etc. on a mikroprocessor, so could be a bit of fun. ...bit64][bit63...bit32][bit31...bit0]

Comment: This is possible, and I agree that it would be fun, but this isn't part of my design and I don't know enough about bitwise operators, if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way you do addition: just calculate `a[i]-b[i]` and then 'carry' values the same way you do it in addition:

```
c[i+1] += c[i] / 10
c[i] %= 10
```

You will only have to ensure that for negative values the division is done according to proper mathematical rules, not like computers do (i.e. (-3)%10=7, and (-3)/10=-1). The simplest way for this is to write

```
c[i+1] +=(c[i]+10)/10 - 1
c[i] = (c[i]+10)%10
```

Another very interesting idea is not to use digits 0, 1, ..., 9, but -5, -4, -3, ..., 4 (and still base 10). Any integer, be it positive or negative, can be represented this way, you will not need the `isPositive` field. For example, 17 is presented as {2 -3} that is 2*10+(-3)*1, and -9 is {-1 1}, i.e. (-1)*10+1*1. You will have a more difficult `toString` method, but your addition and subtraction will be simpler. You will not need to check `isPositive`, and codes will be very similar.

Comment: Hey dude, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have handling of `isPositive` working for `operator+`, just invert `isPositive` for the right hand side of your `-` operator and call through to `+` to let it do the work.

Comment: Known, part of my design plan, but thanks for the note :)
I'm "forced" to work TDD so I think of things ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical subtraction algorithm uses "borrows" instead of the "carries" that appear in addition algorithms. For example, 2935-1369 can be accomplished via

- 5-9 is negative, so you need to borrow a 1 from the "3" in 2935. This gives you 15-9, or 6, plus 2920-1360.
- 2-6 is negative, so you need to borrow a 1 from the "9" in 2920. This gives you 12-6, or 6 (now multiplied by ten), plus 2800-1300.
- 8-3=5, so no problem.
- 2-1=1, so again, no problem.
- The result is 1566.

Dealing with 2935-2936 is a beast of a different color. Since this is a homework assignment (or appears to be one), I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I've thought of it, and then there's also when you try to borrow from a zero, you need to borrow from the next number

Comment: @GioraGuttsait - So what's the problem? Do exactly what you were taught at a very young in determining 1000-997.

Comment: We don't get any assitance or even guidance beyond approval of design,
this is part of the training.
We ought to use google and obviously stackoverflow to find answers. Constantly having around 5-10 open tabs in my brower on my phone

Comment: Get a piece of paper, write down one number above the other so the digits line up, draw a line underneath, and below that do the subtraction manually like you were taught as a child. Then step through it again, very slowly, noting exactly what steps you performed and why. Then write code to do those steps. You don't need 5 tabs or a phone, just paper.